# openssl, python requests error: "certificate verify failed"

Tags: python, openssl, python-requests

If I run the following command from my development box:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect github.com:443
```

I get the following last line of output:

```
Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
```

If I try to do this with requests I get another failed request:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('https://github.com/', verify=True)
```

With an exception raised:

```
SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:507: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

I can also run the first command with the verify flag and get similar output:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect github.com:443 -verify 9
...
Verify return code: 27 (certificate not trusted)
```

Basically this is telling me that there is a problem with the certificates. I can specify a specific certificate with both methods and it will work:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect github.com:443 -CAfile /etc/ssl/certs/DigiCert_High_Assurance_EV_Root_CA.pem -verify 9
...
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

and:

```
>>> r = requests.get('https://github.com/', verify='/etc/ssl/certs/DigiCert...pem')
<Response [200]>
```

So, to my question, **what exactly is wrong here? Shouldn't requests/openssl already know where to find valid certs?**

Other Info:

- Python==2.7.6
- requests==2.2.1
- openssl 0.9.8h

Also, I know passing `verify=False` to the `requests.get` method will work too, but I do want to verify.

**EDIT**

I've confirmed that, as @Heikki Toivonen indicated in an answer, specifying the -CAfile flag for the version of openssl that I'm running works.

```
$ openssl s_client -connect github.com:443 -CAfile `python -c 'import requests; print(requests.certs.where())'`
...
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

So there is nothing wrong with the version of openssl that I'm running, and there is nothing wrong with the default cacert.pem file that requests provides.

Now that I know openssl is meant to work that way, that the CAfile or the place to find certs has to be specified, I'm more concerned about getting requests to work.

If I run:

```
>>> r = requests.get('https://github.com/', verify='path to cacert.pem file')
```

I'm still getting the same error as before. I even tried downloading the cacert.pem file from http://curl.haxx.se/ca and it still didn't work. requests only seems to work (on this specific machine) if I specify a specific vendor cert file.

*A side note: On my local machine everything is working as expected. There are several difference between the two machines though. I so far haven't been able to determine what the specific difference is that causes this issue.*

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> If I run the following command from my development box:
>
> ```
> $ openssl s_client -connect github.com:443
> ```
>
> I get the following last line of output:
>
> ```
> Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
> ```

You are missing `DigiCert High Assurance EV CA-1` as a root of trust:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect github.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert High Assurance EV CA-1
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/businessCategory=Private Organization/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=US/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2=Delaware/serialNumber=5157550/street=548 4th Street/postalCode=94107/C=US/ST=California/L=San Francisco/O=GitHub, Inc./CN=github.com
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV CA-1
 1 s:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV CA-1
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
---
Server certificate
...
Start Time: 1393392088
Timeout   : 300 (sec)
Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
```

Download `DigiCert High Assurance EV CA-1` from [DigiCert Trusted Root Authority Certificates](https://www.digicert.com/digicert-root-certificates.htm):

```
$ wget https://www.digicert.com/CACerts/DigiCertHighAssuranceEVCA-1.crt
--2014-02-26 00:27:50--  https://www.digicert.com/CACerts/DigiCertHighAssuranceEVCA-1.crt
Resolving www.digicert.com (www.digicert.com)... 64.78.193.234
...
```

Convert the DER encoded certifcate to PEM:

```
$ openssl x509 -in DigiCertHighAssuranceEVCA-1.crt -inform DER -out DigiCertHighAssuranceEVCA-1.pem -outform PEM
```

Then, use it with OpenSSL via the `-CAfile`:

```
$ openssl s_client -CAfile DigiCertHighAssuranceEVCA-1.pem -connect github.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert High Assurance EV CA-1
verify return:1
depth=0 businessCategory = Private Organization, 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3 = US, 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2 = Delaware, serialNumber = 5157550, street = 548 4th Street, postalCode = 94107, C = US, ST = California, L = San Francisco, O = "GitHub, Inc.", CN = github.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/businessCategory=Private Organization/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=US/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2=Delaware/serialNumber=5157550/street=548 4th Street/postalCode=94107/C=US/ST=California/L=San Francisco/O=GitHub, Inc./CN=github.com
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV CA-1
 1 s:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV CA-1
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/businessCategory=Private Organization/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=US/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2=Delaware/serialNumber=5157550/street=548 4th Street/postalCode=94107/C=US/ST=California/L=San Francisco/O=GitHub, Inc./CN=github.com
issuer=/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV CA-1
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 4139 bytes and written 446 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: 59D2883BBCE8E81E63E5551FAE7D1ACC00C49A9473C1618237BBBB0DD9016B8D
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: B6D2763FF29E77C67AD83296946A4D44CDBA4F37ED6F20BC27602F1B1A2D137FACDEAC862C11279C01095594F9776F79
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1393392673
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

---

> Shouldn't requests/openssl already know where to find valid certs?

No. OpenSSL trusts nothing by default. Its a polar opposite of a browser's model, where nearly everything is trusted by default.

---

```
 $ openssl s_client -connect github.com:443 -CAfile `python -c 'import requests; print(requests.certs.where())'`
 ...
 >>> r = requests.get('https://github.com/', verify='path to cacert.pem file')
```

Why would you trust hundreds of CAs and subordinate CAs (re: `cacert.pem`) when you know the one CA that is certifying the public key for the site? Trust the one required root and nothing more: `DigiCert High Assurance EV CA-1`.

Trusting everything - as in the browser's model - is what allowed Comodo Hacker to spoof certificates for Gmail, Hotmail, Yahoo, etc when the Diginotar root was compromised.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Thank you for walking through and explaining each piece.

Answer (score 9):

From Request 2.4.0 the author [recommends](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#ca-certificates) using [certifi](http://certifi.io), which is a collection of Root Certificates. There's a python package for it:

```
pip install certifi
```

Comment: quickly solved my issues (on python3.4, requests 2.6.2, openssl 1.0.1k), +1

Comment: To clarify: for requests 2.4.0 and later, if certifi is installed, requests will automatically use it. All you need to do is run that pip command and possibly restart your code.

Answer (score 1):

openssl s_client by default will not use the CA certificates file it ships with, but it does try to verify the connection. This is the reason why your test fails without any parameters and works with -CAfile.

Similarly, Requests tries to verify the connection by default, but it seems it doesn't know where the CA certificates are. This might be a configuration issue in your environment when building/installing OpenSSL, Python or Requests. I say this because the Requests website shows your example working against https://github.com without needing to set the CA path.

Answer (score 0):

I use `openSUSE tumbleweed` and `Windows`, I could install and download new model files without any issues.

Yesterday I got my M`ac mini m2` and I've installed `katrain`.
Later I tried to download models, then I have also errors for certificate. I am not sure that is an issue with certificate. So I checked `cacert.pem` under `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ca-certificates/2023-01-10/share/ca-certificates`.
I tried to check and display details of this `cacert.pem` to add to system, I got a message like `it is invalid format or too big`.

Run `openssl s_client -connect github.com:443` no issue.

So I work around this issue by copy `*.bin.gz under ~/.katrain` on my tumbleweed to `/Users/$username/.katrain` on Mac mini
Then katrain found the model files :)