# certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, ssl, openssl

I am trying to get data from the web using python. I imported urllib.request package for it but while executing, I get error:

```
certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1045)
```

- I am using Python 3.7 on Mac OS High Sierra.
- I am trying to get CSV file from:
  https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/production/course_1606/datasets/winequality-red.csv

When I changed the URL to 'http' - I am able to get data. But, I believe, this avoids checking SSL certificate.

So I checked on the internet and found one solution:
Run `/Applications/Python\ 3.7/Install\ Certificates.command`

This solved my problem. But I have no knowledge on SSL and the likes. Can you help me understand what it actually did to solve my issue.

If possible, please recommend me any good resource to learn about the security and certificates. I am new to this.

Thanks!

Note: I did go through the link - [openssl, python requests error: "certificate verify failed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22027418/openssl-python-requests-error-certificate-verify-failed)

My question differs from the one in link because, I want to know what actually happens when I install `certifi` package or run `Install\ Certificates.command` to fix the error. I have a poor understanding of securities.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [openssl, python requests error: "certificate verify failed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22027418/openssl-python-requests-error-certificate-verify-failed)

Comment: @stovfl - I read from the link provided you. Just to clear (I don't know SSL and the likes):

1. Is OpenSSL library native to the OS I am using or Python uses its own?

2. When my code is trying get data from a particular website, it checks for the website's certificate in the OpenSSL root and as it doesn't trust it by default, it throws me the error. Am I right?

3. If so, then what happens when I run install Certificates.command?

Comment: *1.* Yes, `pyopenssl` is a wrapper to this. *2.* Didn't know if `requests` uses `pyopenssl` at all, but faild to verify the certificate which results throwing the error. *3.* Didn't know `Certificats.command`, assume update/install the needed Certificates, `requests` needs.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50236117/scraping-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error-for-http-en-wikipedia-org
It's answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50236117/scraping-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error-for-http-en-wikipedia-org)

Answer (score 375):

For anyone who still wonders on how to fix this, i got mine by installing the "`Install Certificates.command`"

Here is how I did,

[image: Install Certificates.commad location]

Just double click on that file wait for it to install and in my case, you will be ready to go

Comment: How exactly do you install it? With brew? Please explain

Comment: It's a `.command` file, which means you should just be able to double-click it and it will run in the Terminal.

Comment: It was very useful for me. I had same issue (macOS high Sierra + Python 3.7). Thank you!

Comment: but where do you get this file?

Comment: @JosephAstrahan it is the standard python installation package from www.python.org . Also this is the official python release (I usually install this instead of the one from homebrew)

Comment: I had permission errors so I had to first run ```sudo pip install --upgrade certifi``` in the terminal, and then double-click ```Install Certificates.command```

Comment: With brew, this worked for me:

`security find-certificate -a -p > ~/all_mac_certs.pem; export SSL_CERT_FILE=~/all_mac_certs.pem; export REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=~/all_mac_certs.pem`

Comment: Worked for me. Using Python 3.9.

Comment: @Pynchia to run `terminal > cd /Applications/{Python3.x}` then `terminal > ./Install\ Certificates.command`

Comment: My Python 3.10 installation was done using Scoop, on Windows, and I can't find the file `Install Certificates.command`.

Answer (score 63):

Creating a symlink from OS certificates to Python worked for me:

```
ln -s /etc/ssl/* /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/etc/openssl
```

(I'm on macOS, using `pyenv`)

Comment: I'm using Python 3.9.3 through brew, and for me the command was `ln -s /etc/ssl /usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1`

Comment: It works on mac air M1.

Comment: Worked on Macbook 13 Intel 2020 Ventura 13.2.0

Comment: Worked on MacBook Pro 16 Intel Ventura 13.2.1

Comment: worked for me, just make sure the version is correct
ln -s /etc/ssl/* /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/{python_version_you_have_installed}/etc/openssl

Answer (score 46):

I hit the same issue on OSX, while my code was totally fine on Linux, and you gave the answer in your question!

After inspecting the file you pointed to `/Applications/Python 3.7/Install Certificates.command`, it turned out that what this command replaces the root certificates of the default Python installation with the ones shipped through the `certifi` package.

`certifi` is a set of root certificates. Each SSL certificate relies a chain of trust: you trust one specific certificate because you trust the parent of that certificate, for which you trust the parent, etc. At some point, there is no "parent" and those are "root" certificates. For those, there is no other solution than bundling commonly trusted root certificates (usually big trust companies like eg. "DigiCert").

You can for instance see the root certificates in your browser security settings (for instance for Firefox->Preference->Privacy and security->view certificates->Authorities).

Coming back to the initial problem, and prior to running the `.command` file, executing this returns for me an empty list on a clean installation:

```
import os
import ssl                                        
openssl_dir, openssl_cafile = os.path.split(      
    ssl.get_default_verify_paths().openssl_cafile)
# no content in this folder
os.listdir(openssl_dir)
# non existent file
print(os.path.exists(os.path.join(openssl_dir, openssl_cafile)))
```

This means that there is no default certificate authority for the Python installation on OSX. A possible default is exactly the one provided by the `certifi` package.

After that, you just can create an SSL context that has the proper default as the following (`certifi.where()` gives the location of a certificate authority):

```
import platform
# ...

ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
ssl_context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
ssl_context.check_hostname = True
ssl_context.load_default_certs()

if platform.system().lower() == 'darwin':
    import certifi
    ssl_context.load_verify_locations(
        cafile=os.path.relpath(certifi.where()),
        capath=None,
        cadata=None)
```

and make request to an `url` from python like this:

```
import urllib
# previous context
https_handler = urllib.request.HTTPSHandler(context=ssl_context)

opener = urllib.request.build_opener(https_handler)
ret = opener.open(url, timeout=2)
```

Answer (score 35):

**For those who this problem persists: -**
Python 3.6 (some other versions too?) on MacOS comes with its own private copy of OpenSSL. That means the trust certificates in the system are no longer used as defaults by the Python ssl module. To fix that, you need to install a *certifi* package in your system.

You may try to do it in two ways:

1) Via PIP:

```
pip install --upgrade certifi
```

2) If it doesn't work, try to run a Cerificates.command that comes bundled with Python 3.6 for Mac:

```
open /Applications/Python\ 3.6/Install\ Certificates.command
```

One way or another, you should now have certificates installed, and Python should be able to connect via HTTPS without any issues.

Hope this helped.

Comment: After so many attempts and suggestions from various sources, #2 worked for me! Thanks so much!

Comment: This is the actual fix, without having to adjust your code. Thanks! Works on M1 Macbook Pro with macOS Ventura

Comment: I had the same error while connecting to SMTP (from Mac). The most simple solution that I have seen in this thread.

Comment: Still working in 2024 with python3.12

Comment: Had this problem in Pycharm on MacOS. Had to restart the PC after this for it to work

Answer (score 30):

This worked in all OS:

```
import ssl
import certifi
from urllib.request import urlopen

request = "https://example.com"
urlopen(request, context=ssl.create_default_context(cafile=certifi.where()))
```

Comment: What is `request` defined as?

Comment: Copy-pasted this into my python 3.10 installation on MacOS 13.0.1 and got the same error I've started seeing recently: `urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)>`

Answer (score 29):

Environment: Mac, Python 3.10, iTerm,

1. Search in Finder: Install Certificates.command 
   [image]
2. Get Info
   [image]
3. Open with: iTerm.app 
   [image]
4. double click 'Install Certificates.command'

Waiting for install the certificates. Solve it.

Comment: On thing worked for me.

Comment: Thanks so much, finally an answer that doesn't involve copying cryptic commands

Answer (score 23):

As the question don't have the tag [macos] I'm posting a solution for the same problem under ubuntu :

```
sudo apt install ca-certificates
sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh
export SSL_CERT_DIR=/etc/ssl/certs
```

Solution come form [Zomatree](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/5968#issuecomment-716222434)  on Github.

Comment: This is the answer for Debian.  Thanks

Answer (score 21):

This worked for me on Mac OS:

```
ln -s /etc/ssl/* /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/etc/openssl/
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: ran that exact command and it worked for me! thanks

Answer (score 13):

I would like to provide a reference. I use cmd + space, then type `Install Certificates.command`, and then press Enter. After a short while, the command line interface pops up to start the installation.

```
 -- removing any existing file or link
 -- creating symlink to certifi certificate bundle
 -- setting permissions
 -- update complete
```

Finally, it fixes the errors.

Answer (score 9):

[`Certifi`](https://pypi.org/project/certifi/) provides Mozilla’s carefully curated collection of Root Certificates for validating the trustworthiness of SSL certificates while verifying the identity of TLS hosts. It has been extracted from the [Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) project.

```sh
pip install certifi
```

Or running the program code below:

```py
# install_certifi.py
#
# sample script to install or update a set of default Root Certificates
# for the ssl module.  Uses the certificates provided by the certifi package:
#       https://pypi.python.org/pypi/certifi

import os
import os.path
import ssl
import stat
import subprocess
import sys

STAT_0o775 = ( stat.S_IRUSR | stat.S_IWUSR | stat.S_IXUSR
             | stat.S_IRGRP | stat.S_IWGRP | stat.S_IXGRP
             | stat.S_IROTH |                stat.S_IXOTH )


def main():
    openssl_dir, openssl_cafile = os.path.split(
        ssl.get_default_verify_paths().openssl_cafile)

    print(" -- pip install --upgrade certifi")
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable,
        "-E", "-s", "-m", "pip", "install", "--upgrade", "certifi"])

    import certifi

    # change working directory to the default SSL directory
    os.chdir(openssl_dir)
    relpath_to_certifi_cafile = os.path.relpath(certifi.where())
    print(" -- removing any existing file or link")
    try:
        os.remove(openssl_cafile)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
    print(" -- creating symlink to certifi certificate bundle")
    os.symlink(relpath_to_certifi_cafile, openssl_cafile)
    print(" -- setting permissions")
    os.chmod(openssl_cafile, STAT_0o775)
    print(" -- update complete")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Brew has not run the Install Certificates.command that comes in the Python3 bundle for Mac.

Answer (score 9):

Suddenly I started facing this issue in my windows environment. To aggravate, it was showing up when I ran pip as well, so the issue was not with the remote server certificate.

After trying many different things, I've found the solution combining bit and pieces from multiple answers:

- Add trusted hosts to pip.ini: pip config set global.trusted-host "pypi.org files.pythonhosted.org pypi.python.org" (doesn't work only passing as pip install parameter)
- Update system certificates: pip install pip-system-certs (doesn't work installing python-certifi-win32)

Now https requests are working again \o/

Comment: My company uses Zscaler and this was all it took.  Thanks Orez.

Comment: My company uses Zscaler and this failed to fix the issue. I'm still getting ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129). Also I get a permission denied when I execute /Applications/Python\ 3.7/Install\ Certificates.command :(

Comment: Second option worked for me that uses Zscaler but now Zscaler is blocking me. At least 1 problem is now fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

The cause for this error in my case was that OPENSSLDIR was set to a path which did not contain the actual certificates, possibly caused by some upgrading / reinstallation.

To verify this if this might be the case for you, try running:

```
openssl s_client -CApath /etc/ssl/certs/ -connect some-domain.com:443
```

If you remove the `-CApath /etc/ssl/certs/` and get a `20` error code, then this is the likely cause. You can also check what the OPENSSLDIR is set to by running `openssl  version -a`.

Since changing the OPENSSLDIR requires re-compilation, I found the easiest solution to be just creating a symlink in the existing path: `ln -s /etc/ssl/certs your-openssldir/certs`

Comment: I get error_20 with one version of openssl in one machine, but not the others. The -CApath thing is irrelevant

Comment: Could be that the two versions of openssl each look in different CA paths?

Comment: Turns out the system’s OpenSSL certs were old, and installing OpenSSL from source doesn’t bring new certs. An os upgrade solved it (it was a supercomputer with centos 7 on all nodes)

Answer (score 6):

Paste the following code at the start:

```
# paste this at the start of code
import ssl 

try:
    _create_unverified_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
except AttributeError:
    pass
else:
    ssl._create_default_https_context = _create_unverified_https_context
```

Comment: Am I correct in assuming, this avoids checking the SSL certrificate's validity?

Comment: This skips the certificate validation.

Comment: Don't do this! "My house key doesn't work! Just leave the door unlocked all the time."

Answer (score 5):

I had the error with conda on linux.  My solution was simple.

```
conda install -c conda-forge certifi
```

I had to use the conda forge since the default certifi appears to have problems.

Answer (score 4):

This page is the top google hit for "certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate", so while this doesn't directly answer the original question, below is a fix for a problem with the same symptom. I ran into this while trying to add TLS to an xmlrpc service. This requires use of the fairly low-level `ssl.SSLContext` class. The error indicates that a certificate is missing. The fix was to do several things when constructing `SSLContext` objects:

First, in the client:

```py
def get_client():
    context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
    # Load the default certs:
    context.load_default_certs()

    # Optionally, install the intermediate certs.
    # This _should_ be handled by the server, but
    # maybe helpful in some cases.
    # context.load_verify_locations('path/to/ca_bundle.crt')
    return xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('https://server.yourdomain.com/', context=context)
```

In the server, you need to install the intermediate certs in the context:

```py
class SecureXMLRPCServer(socketserver.TCPServer, 
        xmlrpc.server.SimpleXMLRPCDispatcher):
    # https://gist.github.com/monstermunchkin/1100226
    allow_reuse_address = True

    def __init__(self, addr, certfile, keyfile=None,
            ca_bundle=None,
            requestHandler=xmlrpc.server.SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler,
            logRequests=True, allow_none=False, encoding=None, 
            bind_and_activate=True, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2):
        self.logRequests = logRequests

        # create an SSL context
        self.context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl_version)
        self.context.load_default_certs()

        # The server is the correct place to load the intermediate CA certificates:
        self.context.load_verify_locations(ca_bundle)
        self.context.load_cert_chain(certfile=certfile, keyfile=keyfile)

        xmlrpc.server.SimpleXMLRPCDispatcher.__init__(self, allow_none, 
                encoding)
        # call TCPServer constructor
        socketserver.TCPServer.__init__(self, addr, requestHandler, 
                bind_and_activate)

        if fcntl is not None and hasattr(fcntl, 'FD_CLOEXEC'):
            flags = fcntl.fcntl(self.fileno(), fcntl.F_GETFD)
            flags |= fcntl.FD_CLOEXEC
            fcntl.fcntl(self.fileno(), fcntl.F_SETFD, flags)

    def get_request(self):
        newsocket, fromaddr = self.socket.accept()
        # create an server-side SSL socket
        sslsocket = self.context.wrap_socket(newsocket, server_side=True)
        return sslsocket, fromaddr
```

Answer (score 4):

Caveat: I am not super knowledgeable about certificates, but I think this is worth checking early.

Before spending any time reconfiguring your code/packages/system, make sure it isn't an issue with the server you are trying to download from.

I think the error can be misleading because "unable to get local issuer certificate" makes it seems like it's a problem with your local machine, but that may not necessarily be the case.

Try changing the page you are trying to load to something that is probably good, like `https://www.google.com` and see if the issue persists. Additionally, check the domain that's giving you problems against the search tool at https://www.digicert.com/help/.

In my case, DigiCert's tool told me that "The certificate is not signed by a trusted authority (checking against Mozilla's root store)." That would explain why I seemed to have the root certificates installed but still had the error. When I tested loading a different site with HTTPS, I had no issues.

If this case applies to you, then I think you probably have 3 logical options (in order of preference): 1) fix the server if it's under your control, 2) disable certificate checking while continuing to use HTTPS, 3) skip HTTPS and go to HTTP.

Comment: I still don't understand this. Until a couple of days before my program worked just fine. Then suddenly out of the blue I get this error message. I am still not sure if the problem lies with myself or the site I am trying to reach. I somehow can get a response when sending a GET request to Google, but not to the (unrelated URLs) of two sites I try to reach... this is driving me nuts

Answer (score 4):

Experienced this on Windows and after struggling with this, I downloaded the chain of SSL Certificates for the webpage

Steps for this on Chrome - (the padlock on the top left ->  tap "Connection is secure" -> tap "Certificate is valid")
To view the certificate chain, select the Certification path.
To download each certificate, view the certificate in "Certification Path" tab open  the "details" tab then copy to file

Once downloaded, open where you save the certificates, then compile into one .PEM file

Use this as an example:

```
    openssl x509 -in inputfilename.cer -inform DER -outform PEM  >> .pem
```

The order of this matters, start with the lowest certificate in the chain otherwise your bundle will be invalid

Finally

```
    response = requests.get('enter/urll/here', verify ='/path/to/created bundle')
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply run this:

`pip install --trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org --user pip-system-certs'`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This command legit does nothing

Answer (score 3):

For me all the suggested solutions didn't work. However, I was running the code in a terminal from my companies' PC, which has an IT security software package installed called ZScaler. Disabling the ZScaler software solved all my issues.

Comment: Same problem here, with Z-Scaler as well but when I turned it OFF, I still get the same error

Comment: I was facing the same issue - turning off ZScaler didn't help, but the issue was solved when I quit ZScaler and ran it again.

Comment: Here are the official Zscaler recommendations https://community.zscaler.com/t/installing-tls-ssl-root-certificates-to-non-standard-environments/7261

Answer (score 3):

I experienced this error after installing Python 3.11 with Homebrew, and also when installing with Pyenv (which was itself installed with Homebrew).

I resolved it by reinstalling Homebrew's `ca-certificates` and `openssl` packages:

```
brew reinstall ca-certificates openssl
```

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was that I was setting `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` in my `.bash_profile`

```
/Users/westonagreene/.bash_profile:
...
export REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem
...
```

Once I set `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` to blank (i.e. removed from .bash_profile), `requests` worked again.

```
export REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=""
```

The problem only exhibited when executing python `requests` via a CLI (Command Line Interface). If I ran `requests.get(URL, CERT)` it resolved just fine.

Mac OS Catalina (10.15.6).
Pyenv of 3.6.11.
Error message I was getting: `[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)`

This answer elsewhere: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64152045/4420657

Answer (score 1):

This might be not directly related to the issue experienced by the user, but this error also appears if your machine that sends a request is not allowed to communicate with that address at all, perhaps due to security rules of your company or internet provider. Please try to use "curl https://your-resuouce-name" and ensure you have read access before actually fixing the certificates.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this issue while connecting to MongoDB Atlas. I updated to the latest `certifi` python package and it works now.

(python 3.8, upgraded to certifi 2020.4.5.1, previously certifi version 2019.11.28)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this on Ventura with python 3.9-10, even though I had already tried this:

1. added my private CA certificates to /etc/ssl/cert.pem, /etc/ssl/certs/
2. added my private CA certificates to the certifi specific cert.pem file
3. added my private CA certificates to my keychain into the 'System' bucket
4. set REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=/etc/ssl/cert.pem

This made requests work, but HTTPSConnection and urllib3 failed validation, so it turns out there is yet a place to add CA certificates:

5. /usr/local/etc/ca-certificates/cert.pem

I believe this is because I have installed openssl via brew, and this sets up the above file, and adds a symlink from /usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem.

So if anyone experiences certificate validation failing after having installed openssl via brew, then this is likely the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I tried several of the above. What worked for me is this :

Add the python certs to your ~.zshrc if you don't have them there:

`export PIP_DEFAULT_CERT=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certs.pem`

- Prevent SSL issues when running Python scripts that use the requests module.

`export REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certs.pem`

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me was to set **SSL_CERT_DIR** environment variable in PyCharm's "Run/Debug configurations":

```
SSL_CERT_DIR=/etc/ssl/certs/
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be setting SSL Context:

```
import ssl

def get_ssl_context() -> ssl.SSLContext:
  return ssl.SSLContext()
```

And then using it while making a new request:

```
urllib.request.urlopen(request, context=get_ssl_context())
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation with @Max which he presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66061833), so I thought that I might be of help if others will run into mine.

I had to install a newer version of python on a system, with SSL support which required a newer version of openssl than the one already installed. After installing openssl in a custom folder and looked at it's content I saw no `cert.pem` file.

I wanted to get the latest one and because I was using python already I used `certifi`:

```bash
pip install -U certifi
```

to get the latest version of it, then ran `python` and in the console:

```py
>>> import certifi
>>> certifi.where()
'/home/.../site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem'
```

after a

```bash
cp /home/.../site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem /usr/local/openssl/cert.pem
```

everything went back to normal and the error was gone. (Update the paths to match yours.)

Answer (score 0):

ln -s /etc/ssl/* /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Your Version/etc/openssl
it works for me

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35761327)

Answer (score -1):

I got the below permission error when running the Install Certificates.command

```yaml
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '../../lib/python3.10/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem' -> 'cert.pem'
logout
```

But, I solve this issue by adding `ssl`, hope it helps.

```yaml
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

Comment: Note: this isn't "solving" the issue, it is just suppressing it. Disabling verification isn't a solution ... but a hack. And how does this relate to the question here in the first place?