# Trying to create a discord bot - doesn't seem to connect to the bot

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been trying to develop my skills in Python and had a project to create a little web scraping bot for Discord.

My full code seems to work (prints what I want it to) but the discord element doesn't seem to connect to the bot.

The error I'm getting is:

```
Carls-MBP:coding carlbrand$ python3 test3.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 924, in _wrap_create_connection
    await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 985, in create_connection
    ssl_handshake_timeout=ssl_handshake_timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1013, in _create_connection_transport
    await waiter
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 530, in data_received
    ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 189, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 774, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test3.py", line 13, in <module>
    client.run(TOKEN)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 598, in run
    return future.result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 579, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 542, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 400, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token, bot=bot)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 258, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 158, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1005, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 476, in _request
    timeout=real_timeout
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 522, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 854, in _create_connection
    req, traces, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 992, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 974, in _create_direct_connection
    req=req, client_error=client_error)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 927, in _wrap_create_connection
    req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discordapp.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)')]
```

The code I'm running (simply to put the bot online) is:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = ''


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Hello Chief')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Of course the TOKEN is also filled in with the relevant key.

I'm using Python 3.7 on macOS Catalina and Atom code editor.

Comment: This seems related: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/423

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52805115/certificate-verify-failed-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate help?

Comment: Thanks i used github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/423  and went to my Python folder and clicked the install Certificates.command audit works now.