# Python 3.9 – reading google sheets file using pandas results in traceback error

Tags: python, pandas, csv, google-sheets

I'm trying to read data from a publicly available google spreadsheet using pandas.

I've been following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t6WSY9D_ORQ&t=59s&ab_channel=RyanJones), yet after running my code:

```py
#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3
import pandas as pd

#  Import data from Google Sheets


sheet_id = "1ierEhD6gcq51HAm433knjnVwey4ZE5DCnu1bW7PRG3E"

df = pd.read_csv(f"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{sheet_id}/export?forat=csv")

print(df)
```

I'm getting these traceback errors:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py",
> line 1342, in do_open
> h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,   File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py",
> line 1255, in request
> self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)   File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py",
> line 1301, in _send_request
> self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py",
> line 1250, in endheaders
> self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)   File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py",
> line 1010, in _send_output
> self.send(msg)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py",
> line 950, in send
> self.connect()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py",
> line 1424, in connect
> self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py",
> line 500, in wrap_socket
> return self.sslsocket_class._create(   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py",
> line 1040, in _create
> self.do_handshake()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py",
> line 1309, in do_handshake
> self._sslobj.do_handshake() ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get
> local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> df = pd.read_csv(   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py",
> line 605, in read_csv
> return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py",
> line 457, in _read
> parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py",
> line 814, in **init**
> self._engine = self._make_engine(self.engine)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py",
> line 1045, in _make_engine
> return mapping[engine](self.f, **self.options)  # type: ignore[call-arg]   File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py",
> line 1862, in **init**
> self._open_handles(src, kwds)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py",
> line 1357, in _open_handles
> self.handles = get_handle(   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py",
> line 558, in get_handle
> ioargs = _get_filepath_or_buffer(   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py",
> line 288, in _get_filepath_or_buffer
> req = urlopen(filepath_or_buffer)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py",
> line 194, in urlopen
> return urllib.request.urlopen(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py",
> line 214, in urlopen
> return opener.open(url, data, timeout)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py",
> line 517, in open
> response = self._open(req, data)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py",
> line 534, in _open
> result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +   File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py",
> line 494, in _call_chain
> result = func(*args)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py",
> line 1385, in https_open
> return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py",
> line 1345, in do_open
> raise URLError(err) urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get
> local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)>

Could someone please help me?

**EDIT:** @Code-Apprentice's answear partially fixed my issue, now I'm only getting these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    df = pd.read_csv(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 605, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 457, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 814, in __init__
    self._engine = self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1045, in _make_engine
    return mapping[engine](self.f, **self.options)  # type: ignore[call-arg]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1893, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(self.handles.handle, **kwds)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 518, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 620, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._get_header
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 814, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 1943, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 54: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52805115/certificate-verify-failed-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice partially, most of the errors are gone, but not all of them.

I'll add an edit to my post.

Comment: For future reference, you should accept the linked question when it solves your current error then post a new question about the new error instead of editing your question to completely replace the original error message. This helps to build a library that other people can find in the future to help solve similar problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in the parameter, `forat` instead of `format`. While I'm not sure that's the issue, that's probably not good.