# Having trouble with Slack API SSL certificate verification using python 3.9.7

Tags: python, ssl, slack-api

I am currently working on coding a simple chat bot application for a slack workspace that I created. I followed a simple tutorial on youtube at the following link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJ5bFv-IRFM&ab_channel=TechWithTim

Essentially, here are the steps that I followed:

1. Create workspace
2. Go to slack api website and click on “Your Apps” in top right hand corner and create app in respective workspace
3. Add chat:write OAuth Scope for bot token scope
4. Install to workspace and copy corresponding workspace token
5. Create two new files in VSCode: bot.py and .env
6. In .env, add copied slack token into a variable
7. import libraries, modules, API etc. in bot.py file (code supplied below)
8. Connect app to "chat-bot" channel

Here is the code for my bot.py file:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
from dotenv import load_dotenv # loads environment variable file

env_path = Path('.') / '.env' # tells the system where our environment file is located
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)

client = slack.WebClient(token=os.environ['SLACK_TOKEN']) # didn't get an autocomplete for WebClient 
client.chat_postMessage(channel='#chat-bot', text="Hello World")
```

Code to .env file which is in the same directory as my bot.py file:

```
SLACK_TOKEN= (my slack token that I copied from settings)
```

The problem arises when I type the `client.chat_postMessage(channel='#chat-bot', text="Hello World")` line of code. I get an error that tells me that my SSL certificate verify failed. Specifically the error that is generated states: `urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)>`

I have already tried a couple of posted solutions such as...

1. Tried installing /Applications/Python\ 3.9/Install\ Certificates.command but it told me that the requirement is already satisfied
2. Downgraded webhook to version 0.47.0 as referenced by this post: https://github.com/slackapi/python-slack-sdk/issues/334
   I am unable to find anymore solutions to this problem.

If you happen to know what may be causing the issue any insight will be helpful. FYI, I am running the script bot.py using python3 bot.py.

Comment: Can you check if this helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52805115/certificate-verify-failed-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate ?

Comment: I've tried the solutions from that link, unfortunately no success.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command
This download the necessary certificates

```
open /Applications/Python\ 3.7/Install\ Certificates.command
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a potential solution for the issue you were facing:

The error Firebase: Error (auth/network-request-failed) indicates that there was a network issue when Firebase tried to make a request. This could be due to a lack of internet connection or a temporary network glitch.

The specific fixes that helped resolve the issue for you were:

1. Calling email and password from state correctly:

Instead of:

```
handleLogin = (email, password) => {
// ...
}
```

You did:

```
handleLogin = () => {
const { email, password } = this.state;
// ...
}
```

This ensures you're getting the email and password values from your component state.

2. Initializing Firebase auth correctly for React Native:

Instead of:

```
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth(app);
```

You did:

```
import { initializeAuth, getReactNativePersistence } from "firebase/auth";
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const auth = initializeAuth(app, {
persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage)
});
```

This tells Firebase to persist auth data to AsyncStorage, which is needed for React Native.

So in summary, the key fixes were calling state values correctly and initializing Firebase auth properly for React Native. These fixes likely resolved the network error you were facing.