# detectron2 SSLError when loading model from model_zoo

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate, detectron

I'm trying to load a model from detectron2 model_zoo.

Here is what I try:

```
from detectron2.config import get_cfg
from detectron2.engine import DefaultPredictor

cfg = get_cfg()
cfg.cfg.merge_from_file(model_zoo.get_config_file("COCO-InstanceSegmentation/mask_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x.yaml"))
cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS = model_zoo.get_checkpoint_url("COCO-InstanceSegmentation/mask_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x.yaml")

default_predictor = DefaultPredictor(cfg)
```

The above results in an SSLError:

```
URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1091)>
```

I tried to use requests library directly

```
import requests data = requests.get('/detectron2/COCO-Detection/faster_rcnn_R_50_FPN_1x/137257794/model_final_b275ba.pkl')
```

but it gave the error

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='dl.fbaipublicfiles.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /detectron2/COCO-Detection/faster_rcnn_R_50_FPN_1x/137257794/model_final_b275ba.pkl (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1091)')))
```

I'm not certain, but I think 1 of the following is happening:

1. I've reached some max # of attempts to download from this URL & so the server is blocking me.
2. There is an SSL issue and the library which tries to get the file has tried it's max # of times w/o success. So the library now reports this as an error.

Note:

- I saw related but different post at [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED when using pretrained detectron2 model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73279437/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-when-using-pretrained-detectron2-model)

Answer (score 0):

Test if you don't have access restriction to the website:

```
curl --insecure -O dl.fbaipublicfiles.com
```

You should probably get valid **index.html** listing the python packages