# botocore.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, boto3, anaconda3

Hi I am using Anaconda python distribution

`conda activate base # python 3.9`

When I try to execute the following snippet I get this exception

```py
import boto3
client = boto3.client('s3')
response = client.get_object(Bucket='bucketname', Key='/hai')
```

I get the following exceptions

```bash
botocore.exceptions.SSLError: SSL validation failed for https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com//hai 
[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129
```

It was working fine until last week,I remember upgrading request library yesterday so I uninstalled and re installed conda but still the same issue.

I did some research on Stackoverflow  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52805115/certificate-verify-failed-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate) question tell the developer to run  `Install Certificates.command` but I could not find it since I am using anaconda python distribution

Can someone help me to resolve this issue?