# Using pygbag to package PyGame for web results in SSL error

Tags: ssl

Instead of packaging my PyGame game into an .exe using PyInstaller, I am attempting to use the new Python library pygbag to package the game using web assembly to share on a site like itch.io.

I followed a tutorial to try to get a local test in my browser on port 8000... 1) inserted the asyncio code into my game code 2) ran pygbag from the terminal on the specified directory.

Pygbag does some of the build, but then it hits this SSL error. Any thoughts? Thanks.

WARNING: web.get(https://pygame-web.github.io/archives/0.5/default.tmpl) : <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)>
retrying in 5 seconds

On MacOS 11.6.7; Python 3.10.8; pygbag 0.5.0; pygame 2.1.2

ctrl-c quitting, I see another SSL error:

WARNING: web.get(https://pygame-web.github.io/archives/0.5/favicon.png) : <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)>
retrying in 5 seconds

crtl-c quitting again gets it to stop completely.

Answer (score 2):

There was an "Install Certificates.command" file in Applications/Python 3.10/. I double clicked to run it and that solved my problem.

[certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52805115/certificate-verify-failed-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)