# Databricks Python SQL connector certificate verify failed error

Tags: python, databricks

I am connecting to databricks SQL warehouse for the first time on my local machine (MacOS Venture 13.2.1) via Python 3.11

```
from databricks import sql
import os

connection = sql.connect(
                        server_hostname = "hostname",
                        http_path = "http path",
                        access_token = "token")

cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT * from range(10)")
print(cursor.fetchall())

cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

and I get the following error in the first connection line:

```
RequestError: Error during request to server: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)
```

I tried many of the solutions found here with no luck:[certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52805115/certificate-verify-failed-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)

This is a pretty fresh comptuer and Python install, so perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: do you have a http proxy or web firewall configured?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/databricks/databricks-sql-python/blob/f99cdd8a8edfcaca890ab9ff0526d40faee6a381/src/databricks/sql/thrift_backend.py#L73

I literally just finished troubleshooting this problem.

So when you do `sql.connect` you can pass some kwargs, and they'll be passed along to the ThriftBackend, which is where your SSL issue is happening.  You could disable it with _tls_no_verify=True, or use _tls_trusted_ca_file="/path/to/cert.pem"

```
connection = sql.connect(
    server_hostname=server_hostname,
    http_path=http_path,
    access_token=access_token,
    _tls_trusted_ca_file="/path/to/cert.pem"
)
```