# Using ANTLR4 on python grammars

Tags: python-3.x, macos, antlr

I have a problem using antlr4. I installed it using `brew install antlr` and `pip install antlr4-python3-runtime`.

Now when I want to use it with `antlr4 -Dlanguage=Python3 PSLGrammar.g4`.

But this results in those 3 errors:

`ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1131)`

`urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1131)>`

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/lucas/.m2/repository/org/antlr/antlr4'`

I already tried the fix with executing Install Certificates.command inside my Python application folder.

Any other ideas?

Comment: How did you install antlr4? Remove the .m2 subdirectory, and retype `pip install antlr4-tools`. Then, type antlr4 and make sure you get the tool help output. Verify the antlr tool .jar is somewhere under .m2/ (use `find`).

Comment: @kaby76 I used pip3 install antlr4-tools and I am getting the same error. I have manually added antlr4-4.x.jar and antlr4-4.x-complete.jar as well. Can you please point out what I am missing here.

Comment: actually,  Install Certificates.command worked for me. 

@lucas try creating a symlink
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52805115/certificate-verify-failed-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate