# certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)

Tags: python, ssl

im having the following error when i execute a http requests.

`certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)`

I only have the error when i execute with the wifi of the company. If i use my phone internet then the error do not occur. I think this error is something in my company, so is there a soluction i can use?

I found this soluction but it seams to be to MAC and i did not understand it...
[certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52805115/certificate-verify-failed-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)

Exemple:

```
import requests

URL = f"https://www.amazon.com.br/"
response = requests.get(URL)
print(response)
```

Note: Im on windows

Found this other soluction but not working too
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60671292

```
import requests
import ssl

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

URL = f"https://www.amazon.com.br/"
response = requests.get(URL)
print(response)
```