# Unable to send email using celery in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-celery

I'm unable to send email via smtp using celery task and DRF.

I have the following constants in `settings.py`

```
# Celery settings
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0'

# Email settings
EMAIL_BACKEND ='django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = MY_EMAIL
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = MY_PASSWORD
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
```

`tasks.py`

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def send_verification_email(user_email):
    
    send_mail(
        subject="test email",
        message="testing",
        from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
        recipient_list=[user_email],
        fail_silently=False
    )
```

`views.py`

```
class RegisterUserAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    ...
    user_email = ...
    send_verification_email.delay(user_email = user_email)
    ...
```

The error I'm getting is

```
raised unexpected: SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)')
```

Also, if i'm using **console** instead of **smtp** in below **EMAIL_BACKEND**, i'm able to send emails to the console without any problem..

```
EMAIL_BACKEND ='django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

Not understanding how to fix this issue.

Comment: [This solved my issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58525755/13590673)
I Had to install the `Install Certificates.command`

Comment: maybe get rid of `EMAIL_USE_SSL = False`, also I don't think the broker url needs the `/0` part in the end.