# SSL:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED when requesting an OAuth access token from Google

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, flask-oauthlib

I am getting 'unable to get local issuer certificate' when trying to get an access token from the Google service. Any advice?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/urllib/request.py", line 1344, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/http/client.py", line 1327, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/http/client.py", line 1373, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/http/client.py", line 1322, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/http/client.py", line 1081, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/http/client.py", line 1025, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/http/client.py", line 1468, in connect
    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/ssl.py", line 455, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/ssl.py", line 1046, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/ssl.py", line 1321, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)
```

I tried to curl https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token, which works fine and shows that the certificate is trusted.

Comment: please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: If you google that error message there are a lot of questions already about it have you checked them?  https://stackoverflow.com/q/52805115/1841839

Comment: UPDATE - I managed to fix this issue by switching to the Authlib Python library and using their login code sample. Worked like a charm for me!

Answer (score 0):

You can go to spotlight(search bar) and search for "Install Certificates.command" then hit enter.

Or

Macintosh HD-> Applications-> Python3.12 -> double click "Install Certificates.command" file

[Updating python certificates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGW3o.png)