# Install ssl certificates for discord.py in an app

Tags: python-3.x, macos, ssl, discord.py

I am making a python-based mac app that uses `discord.py` to do stuff with discord. As I knew from previous experience making discord bots, running discord bots requires that you run `Install Certificates.command` in your version of python. However, if another users uses this app, I don't want to require them to install python. I took a snippet of code from `Install Certificates.command`, thinking it would put the certificate in the right place on a user's computer. However, a tester got this error running the app on their computer:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Interface.py", line 136, in <module>
  File "installCerts.py", line 25, in installCerts
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/etc/openssl'
[2514] Failed to execute script 'Interface' due to unhandled exception: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/etc/openssl'
[2514] Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Interface.py", line 136, in <module>
  File "installCerts.py", line 25, in installCerts
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/etc/openssl'
```

It's pretty clear what this error is saying: They don't have python (3.8) installed, so it can't put the ssl certificates anywhere (this is because the app is running in a python 3.8 environment).

By the way, the path mentioned in the error is the directory name of the path given by `ssl.get_default_verify_paths().openssl_cafile`.

I'm not super well-versed in the finer points of web connections and stuff like that, so I don't know the exact role of these certificates. Here's my question:

**Is it possible to get this to work without the user installing python on their computer?**

I.e. Can I add the ssl certificates to the app's local python version (as far as I can tell, in my app, python is simply a large bundled exec file)? Is there somewhere deep in the file system where I can put the certificates to let the connection to discord happen? . Pretty much any solution would be appreciated.

**Additional Info:**

*My Code to Install Certificates:*

```py
STAT_0o775 = (stat.S_IRUSR | stat.S_IWUSR | stat.S_IXUSR
                  | stat.S_IRGRP | stat.S_IWGRP | stat.S_IXGRP
                  | stat.S_IROTH | stat.S_IXOTH)

    openssl_dir, openssl_cafile = os.path.split(
        ssl.get_default_verify_paths().openssl_cafile)
    os.chdir(openssl_dir) #Error happens here
    relpath_to_certifi_cafile = os.path.relpath(certifi.where())
    print(" -- removing any existing file or link")
    try:
        os.remove(openssl_cafile)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
    print(" -- creating symlink to certifi certificate bundle")
    os.symlink(relpath_to_certifi_cafile, openssl_cafile)
    print(" -- setting permissions")
    os.chmod(openssl_cafile, STAT_0o775)
    print(" -- update complete")
```

*The error that discord.py throws when the user doesn't have correct certificates installed:*

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 969, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore  # noqa
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1050, in create_connection
    transport, protocol = await self._create_connection_transport(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1080, in _create_connection_transport
    await waiter
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 529, in data_received
    ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 189, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 944, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1125)
```

If you need more info, let me know.

Comment: Would it be possible to change the SSL default verify paths to include wherever I want to put the certificates? Then, if discord references the `ssl.get_default_verify_paths()`, then it would find the location of the certificate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. This was very tough, but I got to an answer after much research. `ssl` in python is basically just a set of bindings for `openSSL`. When you do `import ssl`, it builds an `openSSL` environment (I don't think I'm using the exact right words here). As you could see, it was defaulting to the `openSSL` folder in `Python` because from python's perspective, that is where `openSSL` keeps its certs. Turns out, `ssl.DefaultVerifyPaths` objects have other attributes, namely `cafile`. This was how I made the path to the cert whatever I wanted. You see, when `openSSL` builds, it looks for an environment variable `SSL_CERT_FILE`. As long as I set that variable with `os.environ` before I imported `ssl`, it would work, because `ssl` would find the certificate. I simplified `installCerts` down to the following:

```py
import os
import stat
import certifi

def installCerts():
    os.environ['SSL_CERT_FILE'] = certifi.where()
    import ssl
    # ssl build needs to happen after enviro var is set
    STAT_0o775 = (stat.S_IRUSR | stat.S_IWUSR | stat.S_IXUSR
                  | stat.S_IRGRP | stat.S_IWGRP | stat.S_IXGRP
                  | stat.S_IROTH | stat.S_IXOTH)
    cafile = ssl.get_default_verify_paths().cafile
    os.chmod(cafile, STAT_0o775)
```

And it seems to work fine  on other people's computers now without them needing to install python.

**This question helped me:**

[How to change the 'cafile' argument in the ssl module in Python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55736855/how-to-change-the-cafile-argument-in-the-ssl-module-in-python3)