# How to get word2vec from google's pre-trained model

Tags: nlp, nltk, gensim, word2vec

I want to fetch vector representation of words.
I tried to use GENSIM api but got the same error as here (for Python 3.6):
[ValueError when downloading gensim data set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64425652/valueerror-when-downloading-gensim-data-set)

What is the best way to get the vector out of the pre-trained model?

Answer (score 1):

You can download the compressed vectors directly form the Google link on the page:

https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/

(Search for `GoogleNews-vectors` to find the link about 2/3 through the page.)

Take note of the local file path where you downloaded the file.

Then load the set of vecors as a Gensim `KeyedVectors` model:

```py
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors

goog_model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('/WHERE/YOU/DOWNLOADED/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz', binary=True)
```